# C# How to implement a Save method which performs multiple checks?

Tags: c#

Often I have to deal with a save method which has to check a few things before saving to the database.

Things I check for, for example, are empty properties, and values which depends on other properties.

I am always struggling on how to implement such a things. The questions I ask myself are:

- Should I use a boolean as a return value for the Save method? And in the client code, check of it is false, show the end-user a messagebox with: "Saving failed". But the problem is, I can't show the user *why* saving is failed. So I don't like this one very much.
- In my Save methods, should I throw an Exception? So when a check fails, a Exception is thrown?
- Do nothing. When a check fails, just don't do anything. But I think this is not really a option.

I was wondering, how do you implement this? Is there kind of a pattern?

Comment: What prevents you from returning a status object, or a Tuple, as the validation result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

imho it's not up to the save method to validate the object. It should be valid when Save is called. It's therefore OK to throw an exception if the object is not specified correctly.

As for validation, there are built in framework in .NET which is called DataAnnotations. Use it for easier validations in all layers.

Comment: I think I agree. Before the Save method is called, the 'client' must check for validation. These validation methods are available for the client. SO if the client don't invoke this methods, the Save method may throw an exception. Right?

Comment: Excactly. The client should do validation since it's much easier to show some fancy error messages for the user there. The save method should still do validation, but any errors are unexpected and an exception is therefore the proper way to report that.

Answer (score 1):

You should not return strings but should throw exceptions. You can create specific exceptions like EmptyPropertyException, DateOutOfBoundException etc. and throw them. Now it is up to the client to catch these exceptions to show the right error messages. Using exceptions is better as you may want to show slightly different error messages in different places or may need to use localized strings.

Comment: This is not control flow, if any expected parameters are missing an exception needs to be thrown !!

Comment: Then it's not input validation. Input validation is if the data are in valid ranges, is not empty, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Very nice implementation is offered by Enterprise Library - Validation block. Please see level of details and ease of implementation on following location:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff953192%28v=PandP.50%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It dependes on what you need and on what user needs...
Basicly you could return a string: if is null or empty everything is ok, on the contrary this string is the error. So you can show a MessageBox or take whatever action you please.
Usually I prefer doing nothing server-side (if there is an error) and returning the error itself, so client-side I can take actions or let user decide what to do.
You can even return an exception from server if there is an error or null if everything went ok.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know why the save failed, use an exception that's what they're there for.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use something like result status - an object having boolean property, showing if the operation succeeded or not, a message for user if some error happened and exception which occured.